# How to point GoDaddy domain to static website hosted on S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, godaddy-api

I have a static website hosted on AWS S3 with a public website endpoint that is something like `http://abc-xyz.s3-website.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`

Say for instance, I have a registered domain with the some name say, `abc-xyz.com` which currently provided by Godaddy.

I am trying to link the `abc-xyz.com` with `http://abc-xyz.s3-website.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. I asked GoDaddy, and they suggested me to get an IP address from AWS(hosting provider) which I can add to the A record, in the GoDaddy DNS setting.

I am not sure how can I get a static IP for this publicly exposed `http://abc-xyz.s3-website.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com` endpoint.

Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried CNAME record type in goddady and set the s3 static FQDN  as value?
https://support.learnworlds.com/support/solutions/articles/12000080108-how-to-set-up-your-custom-domain-cname-record-in-godaddy

Answer (score 0):

Turned out, all I needed to do is to do `Forward with masking` as mentioned in the link below:
https://uk.godaddy.com/help/whats-the-difference-between-domain-forwarding-and-masking-32147